# How much bandwidth does google speech recognition use?

Tags: google-chrome

I am using https://github.com/TalAter/annyang to translate speech into text.

After `annyang.start();` has been called, I discovered that the microphone connects to google's speech recognition engine and will only stop streaming data once `annyang.abort()` is called.

It is imperative to know whether I could leave the mic on for passive voice detection or if it is necessary to turn the mic off after a command is given in order to preserve data and bandwidth.

I could not find any statistics regarding how much data google's speech recognition uses.

Is there any documentation on this topic that I missed or how could I measure this myself?

Comment: None.. Google Speech recognition is bundled with chrome and does not use any bandwidth

Comment: @AkshayKhandelwal: The software is, but it sends voice data to Google servers for analysis and recognition.

Comment: have you checked chrome's network tab to see if it utilizes any bandwidth at all? Besides even if it did, it would depend on the sample. if the sample is big the bandwidth consumed will be more

Comment: The network tab was the first thing I checked. It does not seem to register any network activity regarding the microphone.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure if this is standard but here is my findings:

I had a look at the network activity.

After starting the speech recognition service my outgoing bandwidth went from a couple of bytes per second (0 ~ 60 bps) to about 18KB ~ 20KB per second outgoing and about +- 1KB ~ 1.5 KB per second incoming.

This rate seemed to be pretty steady regardless of what noises I made.

+- 20KB per second times 60*60 = 72000KB.

**Conclusion:**

Voice recognition will eat about 72meg per hour if the service is left active.