# How much bandwith does google Speech API use per second?

Tags: google-cloud-speech

Im doing IA project for my work with this API. Besides i need to know how much internet does API use . Its very important for feasibility study thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How much bandwidth does google speech recognition use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37918664/how-much-bandwidth-does-google-speech-recognition-use)

Comment: Is this question about Chrome's speech recognition feature, or is it actually about Google Cloud's [Speech API](https://cloud.google.com/speech/)? If its the latter, the short answer is that it entirely depends on your use case and that you should make sure to follow [best practices](https://cloud.google.com/speech/docs/best-practices).